# Smoothen aspect layer in ArcMap

Tags: spatial, arcmap

I am currently looking at some data that is on a coastline. Unfortunately, when calculating the aspect from a DEM I get a very "noisy" aspect values, especially on the sea:

[image]

I tried to smoothen my DEM with the "Filter" tool but the result is still very ugly when looking at the water. Is there an easy fix to this? The sea and the riverbed should be flat (-1).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this looks like a sea waves.
Best solve is clipping sea and riverbelt. After then you will divide itself and multiply with -1 (in raster calculator). Then mosaic it with your aspect raster. Here are the detailed process steps;

```
Draw polygons for sea and river belt(flat.shp)
Draw polygons for full study area(stdarea.shp)
clip stdarea.shp with flat.shp(out=Aspect.shp)
Clip aspect from river and sea "rasterclip with Aspect.shp" (out=Aspect.tif). 
clip sea and river from aspect "rasterclip with flat.shp"(out=flats.tif). 
Open raster calculator do this;
("flats.tif" / "flats.tif") *  -1 (out=flcalculated.tif)
MosaictoNewRaster "Aspect.tif and flcalculated.tif" (out="FixedAspect.tif")
Best REgards.
```